# App crash while frequent requesting mediafile with exoplayer instances

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error why frequently try to tap exoplayer instances.
normally instances releases and nulls itself on everytime.
But after some tries app freezes and crashes. I am trying to find where is the problem related

```
    2019-04-04 11:40:36.002 540-1196/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com..app.musicplayer/com..app.musicplayer.dashboard.DashboardMusicActivity#0] dequeueBuffer: attempting to exceed the max dequeued buffer count (2)
2019-04-04 11:40:36.110 13761-15052/com..app.musicplayer E/NativeCrypto: AppData::create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
2019-04-04 11:40:36.121 13761-15052/com..app.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com..app.musicplayer, PID: 13761
    java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.newSsl(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:161)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.<init>(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:152)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:149)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:288
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: Do you release the exoplaxer onPause?

Comment: yes of course and exoplayer= null affterwards

Comment: stop(); release(); null

Comment: System.gc (); also not affective